# Gatsby and netlify .env var

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, netlify

Hi everyone I moved my gatsby site to netlify, I installed google-map-react on localhost: 8000 everything works fine my key is in a .env.development file and in a .env.production i saw i must call my var with GATSBY_***** so i made this

```
GATSBY_GOOGLE_API_KEY = "**********************"
```

And i call it in my component Map :

```
const key = process.env.GATSBY_GOOGLE_API_KEY
```

It works well in local but in netlify i go in my settings of my site and Environment variables
I make GATSBY_GOOGLE_API_KEY Variable and his value but i've got an error message :

```
backend.js:6 Google Maps JavaScript API warning: InvalidKey https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#invalid-key
```

I must have missed something but I don't know what thank you very much if you have any leads